# Проблема с подключением модуля в Django

Tags: python, django

Вроде бы подключил модули правильно, но выдаётся следующая ошибка:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'movies/urls'
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Потому что `movies.urls`. `include('movies.urls')`

Comment: Ну и код в следующий раз текстом прикладывайте

Comment: @Mattern Не желаете оформить как ответ?

Comment: Возможно, как время будет :)

Answer (score 0):

Это происходит потому что правильно подключать пути нужно, в вашем случае, так:

```
urlpatterns = [ 
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('/', include('movies.urls')),
]
```

так как мы обращаемся к файлу как к модулю